# Do I need to remove/modify a journal's Latex template style before submitting a paper to arXiv?

Tags: arxiv, preprint

I want to submit a paper to a SIAM journal. Before submitting it I want to put the paper on arXiv.

I've written the paper using SIAM's Latex template files. Is it ok to upload the current version of the paper to arXiv as it is or do I need to remove the templating or modify the paper in some way?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. I expect that the duplicate I chose addresses your question. If you have any concerns left that the duplicate question cannot address, please [edit] your question to focus exclusively on these.